# How to reset variable of seed on loop using stride with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, loops, stride

I want to reset the variable (seed) on loop using stride with Swift.
I have this code perfectly working on C#

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    //something
    i = 0;  //restart this value when necessary
}
```

And I'm trying this with swift

```
for var i in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 1){
    //something
    i = 0;  //I need to reset this value when necessary, but not working
}
```

The variable "i" change for a second, but then returns to the original value and the behavior is different from C#.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that in Swift, but you should also not be doing that in C#, either. Mutating the index of iteration in the loop body means that it's no longer sufficient for readers to read just the `for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)` line to understand what's happening. You're training them to have to paranoidly skim through the whole function body, just to see if the `i` is mutated in a way that would completely change the behaviour of the entire loop. What exactly is your use case? 9/10 times there's a way to rewrite this without a need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander responded, the exact thing you're actually asking to do is villainous. I'm inclined to believe that a [labeled `do` statement](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_labeled-statement) isn't going to be your best option, either, but it's the simplest solution without seeing any more code.

*The following will print* `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

```swift
var condition = true

loopReset: do {
  for i in 0..<10 {
    if condition, i > 5 {
      condition = false
      continue loopReset
    }

    print(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May use

```
var i = 0
while i <= 10 { 
 i += 1 
 // reset if necessary    
}
```